# An alternative proof of the Morse Lemma using Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, morse-theory

I am trying to write out an alternative proof of the Morse Lemma suggested but not completely written in Elementary Classical Analysis by Marsden and Hoffman.

This is my attempt.
Without loss of generality, assume $x_0 = 0$ and $f(x_0) = f(0) = 0$. Use Taylor's theorem to write
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= f(0) + Df_0(x) + \frac12 D^2f_0 (x,x) + \frac12R_x (x,x) \\
&= \frac12 D^2f_0 (x,x) + \frac12R_x (x,x) \\
&= \frac12\langle A_xx,x\rangle 
\end{align*}
such that for each $x$, $A_x = D^2f_0 + R_x$ is a symmetric linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $D^2f_0$ is non-singular, $A_0$ is an isomorphism, and so $A_x$ is an isomorphism if $x$ is near $0$. Let $Q_x = A_0A_x^{-1}$, so $Q_0 = I$ and $Q_x^T = (A_x^{-1})^TA_0^T = A_x^{-1}A_0$ since $A_x$ is symmetric for all $x$. Define the square root $T_x$ of $Q_x$ for $x$ close to $0$ by the power series $T_x = I - \sum_{n=1}^\infty | \binom{1/2}{n} | (I-Q_x)^n$, so its transpose $T_x^T = I - \sum_{n=1}^\infty | \binom{1/2}{n} | (I-Q_x^T)^n$. Note that
$$
Q_xA_x = A_0A_x^{-1}A_x = A_0 = A_xA_x^{-1}A_0 = A_xQ_x^T
$$
So
$$
Q_x^nA_x = Q_x^{n-1}A_xQ_x^T = \cdots = A_x(Q_x^T)^n
$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
T_xA_x &= A_x - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggr |\binom{\frac12}{n} \biggr | (I-Q_x)^nA_x \\
&= A_x - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggr |\binom{\frac12}{n} \biggr | (A_x - nQ_xA_x + \cdots + (-1)^nQ_x^nA_x) \\
&= A_x - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggr |\binom{\frac12}{n} \biggr | (A_x - nA_xQ_x^T + \cdots + (-1)^nA_x(Q_x^T)^n) \\
&= A_x - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggr |\binom{\frac12}{n} \biggr | A_x(I-Q_x^T)^n \\
&= A_xT_x^T
\end{align*}
Let $S_x = T_x^{-1}$, so $A_x = T_xA_x(T_x^T)^{-1} \Rightarrow T_xA_x = Q_xA_xS_x^T = A_0S_x^T \Rightarrow A_x = S_xA_0S_x^T$. Let $h(x) = S_x^Tx$, so
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac12\langle A_xx,x\rangle \\
&= \frac12\langle (S_x^T)^TA_0S_x^T,x\rangle \\
&= \frac12 \langle A_0S_x^Tx, S_x^Tx \rangle \\
&= \frac12 \langle A_0h(x), h(x) \rangle
\end{align*}
and $Dh_0 = (DS_x^T\cdot x + S_x^T)_0 = S_0^T= I$, which is invertible. Hence, by the inverse fuction theorem, $h$ is locally invertible. Let $g = h^{-1}$, so $h \circ g(x) = x$. It follows that $f \circ g(x) = \frac12\langle A_0h \circ g(x), h \circ g(x)\rangle = \frac12\langle A_0x, x \rangle$. Now, since $\frac12D^2f_0$ is an invertible symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, we can use a linear change of coordinates such that $(\frac12D^2f_0)_{ij} = \pm \delta_{ij}$. So $f \circ g(y) = \pm y_1^2 \pm \cdots \pm y_n^2$.

Is my proof mathematically correct and understandable? My math professor would always comment on my proof saying that my notations are sloppy. Also, my linear algebra is terrible, and I'm concerned that I might mess things up somewhere. I am just wondering if this time I got everything correct. Thanks!

Comment: The idea is to absorb the error term $R$ into a matrix $A_x\approx D^2f(0)$. In 1D the error term is $\int_0^x f'''(s)s(x-s)\,ds$, so $A_x = f''(0) + x\int_0^1 f'''(xs)s(1-s)\,ds$. I guess in higher dimensions it is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But I still don't quite see how $A_x$ is symmetric. Also, does this mean $A_0$ is simply $D^2f(0)$?

Comment: In higher dimensions write $f(sx) = h(s)$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $s\in [0,1]$. I guess we have to assume also that $Df(0) = 0$. By Taylor's expansion $h(1) = h''(0)/2 + \int_0^1h'''(s)(1-s)^2\,dt/2$, but $h'''(s) = \sum_{ijk}\partial_{ijk}f(tx)x_ix_jx_k$, so you may take $A_x = D^2f(0) + \sum_i x_i\int_0^1\partial_{ijk}f(tx)(1-t)^2\,dt$, which is symmetric in $(j,k)$.

Comment: In my previous comment I made a mess interchanging two variables $s$ and $t$. Replace every $s$ by $t$.

Comment: I see what you mean, Thanks. Btw, $Df(0) = 0$ by the assumption of the Morse Lemma.